# How can get autosuggest in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have entered my code in my Controller like below

```
function keyup(){
    $this->Note->simple();
    if(strlen($searchq)>0){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getRecord)) {
            <a href="#"> echo $row['name']; <small> echo $row['department'];</small></a>
        } 
        return $row;
    }
}
```

As soon as I entered this one, it doesn't display any info.

What corrections do I require?

Comment: Possible Duplicate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220211/what-is-the-best-library-to-create-an-ajax-auto-suggest-textbox-in-a-web-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

This may help you.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

All the best.